# Universal Studios Japan (Express ticket for child age 3)

Tags: tickets, japan, children

Does a child (3 years old) need an express ticket to Universal Studios Japan if his parents have express passes?

Answer (score 3):

Seems age 4 and under do not require a ticket per their [website](https://www.usj.co.jp/web/en/us/tickets).

> purchase tickets according to their actual age: if they are of ages 4
> to 11 on the day they wish to enter the park, they may purchase
> tickets for children, and if 12 or over the tickets for adults.